# Debugging a Celsius to Fahrenheit Challenge

Tags: javascript

I am learning some more JavaScript and am having trouble getting a temperature conversion exercise to run.

The below is what I've written so far with the code commented out being a formula from an earlier exercise I did from my instruction book.

Here's the code:

```
<!--

Challenge: 
Write a function to take a temperature in Celsius as an argument and return the equivalent temperature in Fahrenheit, basing it on the code from Hour 2.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fahrenheit From Celsius</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var cTemp =40; // temperature in Celsius
// Let's be generous with parentheses
var hTemp = ((cTemp * 9))/5 + 32;
document.write ("Temperature in Celsius: " + cTemp + " degrees<br/>");
document.write ("Temperature in Fahrenheit: " + hTemp + " degrees");
</script>
</body>
</html>
-->


<html>

<head>    
<script>
var cTemp =40; // temperature in Celsius
// Let's be generous with parentheses
var hTemp = ((cTemp * 9))/5 + 32;    
 </script>
</head>

<body>
<script>

function conversion(a, b) {
var a = 10;
var b = hTemp;
alert (conversion);    
}        



</script>

<input type="button" value="Click for Conversion" onclick="conversion() " />
</body>    

</html>
```

Right now when I run the code is displays all the code of the conversion function but doesn't actually convert!

I have been going through this for hours and I feel like the right answer isn't too far away. **My question in a nutshell: What do I need to correct to get this to run properly?**

Help would be appreciated as I am keen to keep coding but have hit a brick wall here.

Answer (score 2):

You have written `alert(conversion)`, which will basically display the function code, since conversion is a reference to the function.

One other thing, your conversion function takes two variables a and b which is unnecessary as you are not passing any parameters while calling it.

Here is what you can do:

```
<html>
  <head>    
    <script>
      function conversion() {
        let cTemp =40; // temperature in Celsius
        let hTemp = ((cTemp * 9))/5 + 32;   
        alert (hTemp);    
      }
   </script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Click for Conversion" onclick="conversion() " />
  </body>
</html>
```

Since you are learning, you should start using best practices. Avoid `var` for variable declaration and use `let` instead, as it is block scoped. Instead of using `alert` you can also use `console.log` to print values in developer console. I would advise you to search for some tutorials on `Google Chrome Developer Tools`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your solution:

### You are passing a `function` to the alert and not the **result of the function**.

In Javascript you can pass around functions as variables. So if you do `alert(conversion)`, you tell the browser to show the actual function code to the user.

To execute the function, you put parantheses after the function name:

```
alert(conversion());
```

### You are declaring argument for your function but not using them

Your function is

```
function conversion(a, b) { …
```

But you call the function without arguments `conversion()`, you could call it with arguments like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click for Conversion" onclick="conversion(40,10) " />
```

### You are overwriting your arguments without using them

But you will see that nothing changes by adding these numbers, it is because you overwrite them in your function anyway `a = 10; b = hTemp`. Also if you want to convert a temperature you only should have one input variable. So let us rewrite your function:

```
function conversion(cTemp) {
    let hTemp = ((cTemp * 9))/5 + 32;   
    alert (hTemp);    
}
```

So now then function accepts an argument called cTemp and then puts out the conversion. You can now call the function with different arguments like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Click to convert 40 C" onclick="conversion(40) " />
<input type="button" value="Click to convert 50 C" onclick="conversion(50) " />
```

Or even better, you can do a prompt:

```
function promptForConversion() {
  let cTemp = prompt("Temperature in Celsius");
  conversion(cTemp);
}

<input type="button" value="Click to convert number" onclick="promptForConversion(50) " />
```

These are very basic principles, I highly recommend to do some more tutorials, that also teach you how to organize your code in reusable functions. Good luck!